# Designing creatives with complex sale mechanics

Tags: information-design, marketing

I'm Designing a set of creatives for sale campaigns (e.g. black Friday) for a fashion e-commerce. These would be in mostly landscape dimensions, but there are also smaller placements.

Compared usual campaigns with no discounts, where there's room to include imagery and persuasive copy, something we didn't anticipate was complex sale mechanics that could take up a lot of the space in creative.

**e.g. up to 50% off + extra 10% off.** 
besides this, there needs to be additional information like **voucher code and T&C** added to the creative.

1 good design solution I came across is this, tho here there is no room for an image and might not work for smaller landscape dimensions and other languages. [image]

of course its possible to just use the sale mechanics as the only copy. with no persuasive copy.

anyone faced such design challenges that know workarounds or solutions to come up with a clean design while retaining the complex mechanics??

Comment: I don't understand what's being asked here. I'm afraid the mechanics would have to be known clearly and any solution would merely be opinion-based.

Comment: @Scott I understand the question, but it is true that it is very broad for a concrete answer. OP doesn't look for a specific design, but an idea of graphic systematization. The only contribution would be ideas or warnings, but not a graphic answer. About knowing the mechanics, it depends of the company size. Big stores located in several states or countries have hundreds of different mechanics, impossible to relate them in a question or give a single design solution.

Comment: @Danielillo as I commented, without knowing the mechanics, this can't be effectively answered.. and answers would be *opinion-based* in my view. You are *guessing* at what mechanics might *possibly be*. That doesn't mean you are correct. And it, by no means, indicates that I'm correct. But I see *"how do I address X"* without disclosing X as impossible to answer.

Comment: @Scott   That's why –the only contribution would be ideas or warnings, but not a graphic answer– as I wrote.

Comment: https://www.lingscars.com/ comes to mind as a shining example of complexity (not particularly a good one) :)

Comment: @scott. Sorry for any confusion, I have updated the question

Comment: @AmeenAkbar I have edited my answer to address your concern about adding an image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One strategy that you can use is sometimes called **Messaging Management** (Packaging Design Workbook, p. 87). It helps your audience to "chunk":

> A way of dealing with or remembering information by separating it into
>   small groups or chunks. -*Cambridge Dictionary*

- group like elements so that your audience feels like there is a
  lesser quantity of elements to make sense of
- use whitespace around
  families of elements to better define each grouping.

[image: Example of Messaging Management]

Above, we have 9 different visual elements (abstracted as circles, these could be logos, pictures, claims, discounts...). Disorganized (left) there seems to be way more to make sense of, vs. when they are properly managed (right).

You mention:

> Though here there is no room for an image and it might not work for
>   smaller landscape dimensions and other languages.

Have you considered something like this?

[image: Added image]

In terms of landscape format, I'm not sure how the website menus affect the space you have available but I am fairly sure you could use the same strategy of cropping 50%, especially that you repeat this number in a smaller point size so it doesn't matter so much if the numbers are difficult to identify; it still puts emphasis on the large rebate.